# CakePHP 2.x IN Clause returns only a single record

Tags: php, cakephp

I am fetching the records using CakePHP's `IN` Clause. But in my page, only a single record is displayed.

Code:

```
$subQuery = array(
    $zip
);

$getAdr   = $this->Driver_location->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Driver_location.zip' => $subQuery
    )
));
```

The `$subQuery` returns multiple ZIP codes:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 751001,751002,751003,751006,751007,751009,751009,751010,751011,751013
)
```

But when I print `$getAdr` using `pr($getAdr);`, only the first record (`751001`) is shown.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Driver_location Should be DriverLocation. Please try to stick to conventions.

Answer (score 1):

`$subQuery` should be an array where each record has to be a zip code, instead of a single index comma-separated element. So it would have to be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 751001,
    [1] => 751002,
    [2] => 751003,
    ...
)
```

If it's like this, then Cake will automatically do the query with an `IN` statement.
So, if $zip is a comma-separated string, simply do:

```
$subQuery = explode(',', $zip);
```